# PyCharm shows no output from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Please go easy on me, its my first days trying to use `python` and I already have problem with setting up enviroment.

When I use `IDLE` with code:

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = ["a,b"]
dataset = pd.read_csv('abdataset', names = column_names, index_col = False)


dataset
```

shows the whole dataset in quite good way.

Whenever when I try same code on `PyCharm` and go `RUN` on the console I can only see

> Process finished with exit code 0

Is there any way to configure run console to show output like `IDLE` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really not PyCharm specific behavior.

Python is an *interpreted* language, i. e. it executes every command *immediately* as you write it and confirm it with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. One command after the other.

But - as in other interpreted languages - you have another option: Write in advance *all your commands into a text file* and then ask Python to perform them *as a batch* - again *one command after the other*, but very fast.

In the *first* case - execution immediately after pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it is comfortable to find of the value of a variable (or of an expression) by simply *writing them* - and Python display it in the standard (sometimes ugly) form. It is performed in the **Python console** environment, available in PyCharm IDE, too (e. g. from menu `View | Tool Windows | Python console`).

In the *second* case (the batch processing of commands) it would be not so comfortable, as commands are executed in a very fast sequence and you are generally not able to tell which output value corresponds to which variable, moreover if you often don't see your commands on your monitor. So in this case (launching a `.py` or `.pyc` file) this approach is not used and you have print them explicitely with the `print` command (Python 2) or `print()` function (Python 3). In PyCharm IDE you perform this action as you did: By running the appropriate **Python file** from your project.

So you have 2 possibilities in PyCharm:

1. Use **Python Console** for writing all your commands, one after the other - *with or without* the use of the `print` command / `print()` function.
2. Run a **Python file** (as you did) but with *explicitly printing what you wanted to be displayed.*

---

Note:

In the IDLE you have *the same* 2 possibilities with *the same* behavior:

- 1<sup>st</sup> immediately after starting the IDLE,
- 2<sup>nd</sup> after opening / creating a Python file and launching it by <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Write Your Code in Print function

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm, if you want to see something displayed in the console you need to explicitly output it. In this case, it should work if you end your code with `print(dataset)` to print it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want pycharm to run an interactive console akin to idle/ipython etc.

Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Python Console and you should get a familiar interactive interpreter that you can use.

When you write and run scripts, you don't get the output akin to what you are looking for.

Comment: but how can I run the script I wrote in editor using this console? :) I opened it, run the script and when i type "dataset" i get error "NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: PyCharm shows no Error No output from pandas

Create small csv file with export>> save as Unicode UTF-8 (in Mac)

```
df = pd.read_csv("tstPandas.csv")
```

read your file and hold "df".
To see output you need to `print(df)`

Which outputs the file

[image]