# Pycharm: importing pandas prevents console output

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I use Pycharm 2018.1, anaconda python 3.6

When I run a script using the configuration in the screenshot, I get its output in the console as expected. Also, I get a command line afterwards. However, if I import Pandas in the same script, no output is generated. This very simple script:

```
print('test')
```

results in 'test' being printed as output in the console window. Simply adding a Pandas import statement as follows

```
import pandas
print('test')
```

makes that I do not get any output.

Why would importing pandas mess up Pycharms behavior?

[image: My screenshot]

ps. I found related question: [PyCharm shows no output from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209506/pycharm-shows-no-output-from-pandas). However, here it is suggested to explicitly print whatever I want to see in the console. I already do so and still Pandas messes up the expected output.

Comment: Sounds similar to [PY-29186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29186). Are you sure the output is not hidden under `Python <version> ...` collapsable block?